# Theory of convergence for this case?

Tags: estimation, convergence

I hope you can guide me to the right place.

I am estimating two equations, where each equation produces an output which is needed in the other equation as input. Something like this:

$Y_t = AX_t + f(\hat W_t) + e_T$

$W_t = BZ_t + f(\hat Y_t) + u_t$

The outputs $f()$ are based on predictions of the dependent variable, transformed through some function. It is not possible to estimate the system jointly. Thus, my only option is to do iterated estimation.

My approach is the following:

1) run $Y_t = AX_t + e_T$

2) predict $f(\hat Y_t)$

3) run $W_t = BZ_t + f(\hat Y_t) + u_t$ (coefficient of the predicted term restricted to be 1)

4) predict $f(\hat W_t)$

5) run $Y_t = AX_t + f(\hat W_t) + e_T$  (coefficient of the predicted term restricted to be 1)

6) iterate 2-5 until some threshold in terms of difference between predicted values between two iterations is met.

In my empirical application, I find that the above algorithm does converge, which is good news, and to a certain extent, all that I need. However, I want some theoretical justification that the method will actually converge, under reasonable assumptions.

How can I know that's the case? Is there some general convergence rule or theorem? Some material online is impossible for me to understand (http://www.its.caltech.edu/~sherman/ils.pdf). Any suggestions? Perhaps a textbook?